# Does GDI+ support graphics acceleration?

Tags: c++, winapi, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to write a screensaver for a Windows platform using C++ and Win APIs. To render graphics I'm using GDI+, but the issue is rendering png's with some small amount of animation (fade-in and -out) becomes very "CPU heavy."

So I was wondering if there's a way to enable GPU acceleration for GDI+ APIs? And if it's not possible, is there something that I can use from a non-managed code that supports GPU acceleration (apart from OpenGL or DirectX)?

Comment: I insist: use Direct3D/Direct2D or OpenGL.

Comment: If so, this is what I get when I try running a screensaver that is built with DirectX support at user logon screen (no logged in users): http://i150.photobucket.com/albums/s99/dc2000_bucket/scrsrn.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  GDI is mostly about manipulation of in memory bitmaps when it comes down to it.  If you want more advanced features, use Direct3D/2D.

Comment: Thanks. There's one catch with Direct2D in case of a screensaver -- it doesn't work as a logon screensaver (or when no users logged on to the workstation.) Any idea how to overcome that?

Comment: This is what happens when I try running a screensaver that is built with DirectX support at user logon screen (no logged in users): http://i150.photobucket.com/albums/s99/dc2000_bucket/scrsrn.png

Comment: @user843732: It clearly says that your application requires a later version of Direct3D which you do not have installed...  I wouldn't call that "not working" in the general sense.

Comment: I have it installed. The same screensaver runs when a user logs in.

Comment: @user843732: I can find all sorts of documentation which shows that it is perfectly possible to use DirectX for screensavers (why wouldn't it be?).  There is something wrong on your end, but I don't know what.  You'll have to do some troubleshooting.

Comment: OK, try it on your Windows? It must have an option to show logon screen enabled. Then add the following to: "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop" key, SCRNSAVE.EXE=C:\Windows\System32\Ribbons.scr, ScreenSaveTimeOut=60, ScreenSaveActive=1. Then reboot your computer and wait until logon screen is shown. Don't log in and wait for 1 minute for the ribbons screensaver to kick in.

Comment: @user843732: Sorry, but I don't have the time for that. Hopefully someone comes a long with a bit more insight.

Comment: I understand... But there's no insight. DirectX does not work when there's no logged in users. Period. I just spent time writing a DirectX screensaver and it works fine with a logged on user but fails to initialize just as a default Windows one does at a log-on screen. So the bottom line -- DO NOT use DirectX for a screensaver if you want it to work everywhere.

Comment: @user843732: Ahh, see, now that you have gone into more detail I can confirm that you are correct (not that you needed me too).  Of course, if you know that already... why are you asking?  It seems you're right though, DirectX won't work when there is no user logged in.  Of course, none of that changes how GDI works unfortunately.

Comment: I just learned it 30 minutes ago and I'm posting it here in case someone else needs to know it...

Comment: @user843732: ...fair enough :D.  It's a shame really, how do they expect you to make a screensaver with DirectX?  Perhaps if you post your current code I could help to optimize it a bit.

Comment: Thanks. There's too much code to post. I'm working on it right now. Basically I'll try to cache a rendered image in a regular GDI's memory DC and reuse it instead of re-rendering it for every frame. I don't think if there's more optimization to do...

Comment: @user843732: how about a sprite sheet?  Store each frame of animation in it.  Nothing to render, simply calculate the x and y coordinates into the sprite sheet depending on what the current frame is.  This is how 2d games do it.  Of course, I don't know how complex your animation is.

Comment: Yeah, good idea. Thanks. By the way, how big can I make GDI's memory device context?

Comment: @user843732: This may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224754/Guide-to-Win32-Memory-DC

Comment: Just interesting, was the situation changed in Win10? or GDI+ is still CPU based calculations?