# Bitmap.MakeTransparent() is too slow

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization, drawing

I use a black and white pictures as a mask to generate nice contours after applying a rectangle. Unfortunately to get rid of the black color I use the `MakeTransparent` method, unfortunately it is very slow, in my code I have to perform such a procedure twice, which in the case of 20 images takes about 5 seconds. Is there any other solution to speed up this procedure?

```
Bitmap contour = new Bitmap(
    imageMaskCountour.Width, imageMaskCountour.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(contour))
{
    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    g.FillRectangle(ContourBrush, 0, 0, contour.Width, contour.Height);
    g.DrawImage(
        imageMaskCountour,
        new Rectangle(0, 0, contour.Width, contour.Height),
        new Rectangle(0, 0, imageMaskCountour.Width, imageMaskCountour.Height),
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

contour.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);
```

Edit:

I try add [LockBitmap](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp) and add the following method:

```
public void MakeTransparent(Color color)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < this.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < this.Width; x++)
        {
            if (this.GetPixel(x, y) == color)
            {
                this.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Transparent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is much slower.

Comment: My first question would be why you have to call it twice per image

Comment: Generates water level in the tank, in the first photo the rectangular simulate the current water level and the mask generates the tank interior shape, and on the second photo generates the tank contour in the correct color. At the end, I combine both bitmaps.

Comment: Can you not run then both detection's concurrently, and merge the 2 at the end?

Comment: Well GDI+ isn't particularly fast at the best of times.  Maybe you should consider WPF - at least it is _hardware-accelerated_ http://stackoverflow.com/a/12171698/585968.

Comment: @BugFinder Unfortunately, this is not possible because the black color of one of the photos will always cover the other part. DrawImage is not too fast either.

Comment: How did you implemenrt the full lockbitmap code? - Also: Did you try to use a direct method that uses lockbits?

Comment: Regarding edit with x-y loops:  yes performing image manipulation at the (x,y) level is always going to be considerably slower than operating on the underlying raster buffer via _pointers_

Comment: `GetPixel`/``SetPixel` is too slow.. Using lockbitmap lock and get/set pixel is useless

Comment: Example: `Size s = bmp.Size;
PixelFormat fmt = bmp.PixelFormat;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, s);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, fmt);
int size1 = bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height;
byte[] data = new byte[size1];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, data, 0, size1);`...

Comment: `for (int y = 0; y < s.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < s.Width; x++)
    {
        int index = y * bmpData.Stride + x * 4;
        if ( data[index + 2] + data[index + 1] + data[index + 0] <= 0 ) data[index + 3] = 0;
    }
}
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData)` for a given Bitmap bmp. You can use a larger value than `0` to allow some tolerance..

Comment: @Jeroen: The Get/SetPixel are methods of the LockBitmap class, not the usual  Bitmap.GetPixel..!

Comment: Also: Sometimes one can hear that using PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb is a lot faster.

Comment: @TaW why post it as comment? Kinda unreadable this way..

Comment: @Joergen A) the link you gave is the link from the OP! b) a comment just to test if it even is faster than the lockbitmap.

Comment: @FaW A, lol I'll remove it.

Comment: @TaW Your method gets very similar results to MakeTransparent, But it helped me with another problem, greatly speeding up my previous solution, so thank you anyway!

Comment: _it helped me with another problem, greatly speeding up my previous solution_ lol, you make me curious..

Comment: In another place I also used Lockbit with the link I gave,
But turning on both loops to get GetPixel () to find the color takes about 1 second, your code copes with that below 10 milliseconds! ;)

Comment: Can I do what I need using OpenGL oraz Direct2D ?

Answer (score 2):

Every operation you are doing on the `Bitmap` requires locking and unlocking of the bits. That makes it very slow. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24702215/8051589) how to access the bitmap data directly by locking once, manipulating all data and finally unlocking it.

The following code is an extension method for a regular `Bitmap` using the direct access just mentioned. It implements the logic of your method. Note that I save the `Height` and `Width` to local variables. Iam doing that because I recognized that it is much slower if used multiple times like in a loop condition.

**Caution:**

The underlying code only works for `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`, [see PixelFormat reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat).
The code gives you an idea how to access the pixel data directly and can be adapted to other pixel formats too.

The following points must be respected if adapting to other pixel formats.

- Byte size of one destination pixel to correctly write the color value.
- The correct row addressing through the `Bitmap.Stride` property, [see Stride for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride). In case of `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` the stride matches the width by: `Bitmap.Stride == Bitmap.Width * 4` and therefore no row address adjustments are needed.

---

```
public static void FastMakeTransparent(this Bitmap bitmap, Color color)
{
    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    unsafe
    {
        int* pixelPointer = (int*)bitmapData.Scan0;

        int bitmapHeight = bitmap.Height;
        int bitmapWidth = bitmap.Width;
        int colorInt = color.ToArgb();
        int transparentInt = Color.Transparent.ToArgb();

        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapHeight; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bitmapWidth; ++j)
            {
                if (*pixelPointer == colorInt)
                    *pixelPointer = transparentInt;
                ++pixelPointer;
            }
        }
    }

    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
}
```

Benchmark with Stopwatch class on my Intel Core2Duo P8400 (2.26 GHz) CPU.

```
Bitmap size 1000x1000 random filled accumulated time of 100 runs
Target AnyCPU .NetFramework 4.5.2

Release build

MakeTransparent      Ticks: 24224801 | Time: 2422 ms
FastMakeTransparent  Ticks: 1332730  | Time: 133 ms


Debug build

MakeTransparent      Ticks: 24681178 | Time: 2468 ms
FastMakeTransparent  Ticks: 5976810  | Time: 597 ms
```